# Show that $\sum\limits_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p}$ ~ ${\log\log{x}}$ when ${x \to \infty}$ (here p is a prime)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I saw that some of you were upset over my last question, so I decided to ask a more interesting question:

Show that $\sum\limits_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p}$ ~ ${\log\log{x}}$ when ${x \to \infty}$
(here the sum goes over all the primes less than or equal to x)

Edit: I've changed the question and wrote it as it appeared in the exam.

Comment: Hint: Google and use Merten's theorem, and you will find that the limit tends to 1.

Comment: @yanbo: the limit does not tend to anything.

Comment: @user64494 Do you think that there is no limit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yanbo is right.

Merten's second theorem states that
$\lim_{n \to \infty}
\big(\sum_{p \le n} \frac1{p}-\ln\ln n \big)
=M
$
where
$M$ is the 
Meissel–Mertens constant.

Dividing by $\ln\ln n$,
we get
$\lim_{n \to \infty}
\big(\frac1{\ln\ln n}\sum_{p \le n} \frac1{p}-1 \big)
=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{M}{\ln\ln n}
= 0
$
(since $\ln \ln n$ goes reluctantly to $\infty$)
so
$\lim_{n \to \infty}
\big(\frac1{\ln\ln n}\sum_{p \le n} \frac1{p} \big)
= 1
$

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Prime Number Theorem, which has [as a consequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number):

$$p_n \sim n \log{n} \quad (n \to \infty)$$

Then

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{p_k} \sim \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k \log{k}}  \sim \int_2^n \frac{dt}{t \log{t}} \sim \log{\log{n}} \quad (n \to \infty)$$

Comment: Note that $p_n \sim n \ln n$, so the sum up to $p_n$ is not the same as the sum for $p_i \le n$. However, $\ln \ln n$ grows slowly enough so the results are the same.

Comment: @martycohen: good point.  Yes, the difference is higher-order, so it does work out.